# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'memoizeOptions' does not exist in type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

This my code:

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const selectNumCompletedTodos2 = createSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.counter.ok.ok,
    (state: RootState) => state.counter.ok.ok,
    (ok: number, ok1: number) => `${ok} + ${ok1}`,
    {

        memoizeOptions: {
            equalityCheck: (a, b) => {
                return a === b;
            },
        }
    }
)
```

I get this error:

> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ memoizeOptions: { equalityCheck: (a: any, b: any) => boolean; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(res1: number, res2: number, res3: string) => unknown'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'memoizeOptions' does not exist in type '(res1: number, res2: number, res3: string) => unknown'.

Comment: This code by itself type checks just fine: https://tsplay.dev/wjkO2N Do you have the latest versions of `@reduxjs/toolkit` and maybe `reselect` installed?

Comment: `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0"`  what do you need reselect ?. I install but it doesn't help

Comment: You shouldn't need `reselect`, but there was a possibility an older version lurked around in your dependencies. What is the type of `RootState`? And do you also get a type error in a module that just contains the definitions of `RootState` and  `selectNumCompletedTodos2`?

Comment: `const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
  },
});

type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;`

Comment: i am getting error when i add this piece of code ` {

        memoizeOptions: {
            equalityCheck: (a, b) => {
                return a === b;
            },
        }
    }`